# Clone inline form fields and append to parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form fields:

```
<div id="filename-url-container">
    <div class="form-inline form-group">
        <input name="filename[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Filename" type="text">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="url[]" class="form-control" placeholder="URL" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-add" type="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to grab the first child each time the button is pressed and append it to the bottom of the `filename-url-container` div **without** the values of the original cloned fields.

I tried to get this to work but it's not appending correctly:

```
$('#filename-url-container').on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formGroup= $('#filename-url-container :first-child');
    $('#filename-url-container').append(formGroup);
    console.log(controlForm);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `.clone` the elements before appending them - as written your code would simply take the existing elements and try to move them to exactly the same place.

You also need to constrain your selector, else it will pick every `:first-child` element within the container, not just the one that's the immediate child:

```
$('#filename-url-container').on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
    var formGroup= $('#filename-url-container > :first-child').clone(true);
    formGroup.find('input').val('');   // erase values
    $('#filename-url-container').append(formGroup);
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/dvqgnga0/

Comment: accepted for actually using clone. I knew it had to do something with that but I couldn't get it to work. The little details :)

Comment: @Ortixx that probably had something to do with your selector being incorrect too - until I correct that I found I was getting an ever-increasing set of new elements added for every click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filename-url-container').on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formGroup= $('#filename-url-container div:first-child').html();
    $('#filename-url-container').append(formGroup);
    console.log(formGroup);
});
```

You need to append html, not object it self.
http://jsfiddle.net/npdh2v3L/

Comment: IMHO, you should `.clone(true)` the elements, not serialise them with `.html()`.  The latter will fail to copy any event handlers that may exist on them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using `:first-child` correctly. `:first-child` refers to the first child of the type to it's left. Other than that you just need to get rid of those values. Additionally, I'm not seeing a need to `Event.preventDefault()` since you are not using a submit button.

```
$('#filename-url-container .btn-add').click(function(){
  var clone = $('#filename-url-container .form-group:first-child').clone(true);
  clone.find('input').val('');
  $('#filename-url-container').append(clone);
});
```

Comment: Sure, but it's inefficient.  Also, why have you rewritten the OP's perfectly good delegated event selector?  That's how the original would have coped with the new button not existing at initial event registration.

Comment: Why write more code, and why would you want to `EventObject.preventDefault()` on a button that doesn't submit?

Comment: You're kind of right about `:first-child`, and your proposed solution should work.  However `:first-child` is a _pseduo_-selector, and affects the value that it's attached to, and with the space in the original it was effectively attached to an implicit wildcard, i.e. `#filename-url-container *:first-child`, thereby selecting _every_ descendent of the container that _is a first child_.  The shorter version in mine is `#filename-url-container > *:first-child`, with the `>` forcing only immediate children, not grand-children, etc.

Comment: p.s. although you've removed the recursion you've still left behind a broken `.click` handler.  Your current version won't handle clicks on the newly added buttons, whereas the OP's original delegated handler using `.on` was exactly correct.

Comment: I thought when I set `.clone(true)` it grabs the Events delegated to the cloned Elements, in this case the first `.form-group`, which at the time of clicking `$('#filename-url-container .btn-add')` does have the `click` Event assigned to it. Please correct me if I fail to understand something.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - since you did indeed register on the `.btn-add` element that is also one of the ones being cloned it does look like you would indeed also copy the event handler.  It's not obvious, though (indeed, I missed it having read your code several times) and the `$(static_parent).on('click', 'dynamic-child', ...)` method is preferred (and better understood)